# How can I pass the value from my API to my head tittle with vue-head?

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue-head in website because of I have to pass the name of the program to the html head, and the inf. it is coming from an API, so I make the request but every time I try to pass the name it send me error this the code:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    programs: [],
    firstVideo: {},
    vidProgram: {}
  }),
},
  created() {
    //do something after creating vue instance
    this.api = new ApiCanal({})
    this.getProgram()
  },
  methods: {
    getProgram() {
      this.api.http.get(`videos/program/${this.programSlug}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.programs = response.data
          this.firstVideo = response.data[0]
          this.vidProgram = response.data[0]['program']
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error
        });
    }
  },
  head: {
  //this is the inf. for the head
    title: {
      inner: this.programs.name,
      separator: '-',
      complement: this.programs.info
    }
  }
}
```

I will really appreciate if you can help me with this issue

Comment: what error? what does it state?

Comment: it doesn't pass any information to the head when use the " inner: this.programs.name " it does pass the data but if I use like the example "   inner: 'Data' " it works I got the Data on the top of the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use properties of your Vue object/component in the `title` there, you need to [make it a function](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head#example-with-files-vue), as currently `this` refers to the object creating your Vue component (probably the global `window` object).

```
head: {
  title: function() {
    return {
      inner: this.programs.name,
      separator: '-',
      complement: this.programs.info
    };
  }
}
```